# Logical Volume not available in /dev/mapper - can't get it to appear

Tags: mount, raid, lvm, development

I inherited an Ubuntu kvm server:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

... which is giving us an error at startup about being unable to mount a partition, giving me the option to Skip or Manually recover. I am not sure how to manually recover?

The system has two physical drives which are RAID mirrored.

In fstab, I see the following entry which is failing:

```
/dev/mapper/primary-data /mnt/data       ext4    defaults        0       2
```

However, that file is not in /dev/mapper:

```
root@vmserver:/dev# ls -al /dev/mapper/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     120 May 18 11:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root    4680 May 18 11:10 ..
crw-------  1 root root 10, 236 May 18 11:07 control
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 May 18 11:07 primary-backup -> ../dm-5
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 May 18 11:07 primary-snap-cow -> ../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 May 18 11:07 primary-system -> ../dm-0
```

When I run vgdisplay, I can see that there are 4 current LVs, but only 2 are open?

```
--- Volume group ---
VG Name               primary
System ID             
Format                lvm2
Metadata Areas        1
Metadata Sequence No  162
VG Access             read/write
VG Status             resizable
MAX LV                0
Cur LV                4
Open LV               2
Max PV                0
Cur PV                1
Act PV                1
VG Size               1.79 TiB
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              469222
Alloc PE / Size       458476 / 1.75 TiB
Free  PE / Size       10746 / 41.98 GiB
VG UUID               ahmMej-0Pzn-V9Fk-0utn-q8PV-K7PU-AWxTQ1
```

If I run `vgscan --mknodes`, I get this output:

```
root@vmserver:/dev# vgscan -v --mknodes
    Wiping cache of LVM-capable devices
    Wiping internal VG cache
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
    Finding all volume groups
    Finding volume group "primary"
  Found volume group "primary" using metadata type lvm2
    Finding all logical volumes
  The link /dev/primary/data should had been created by udev but it was not found. Falling back to direct link creation.
  The link /dev/primary/snap should had been created by udev but it was not found. Falling back to direct link creation.
```

Then, the contents of /dev/mapper look as follows:

```
root@vmserver:/dev# ls -al /dev/mapper/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      180 May 18 11:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root     4680 May 18 11:10 ..
crw-------  1 root root  10, 236 May 18 11:07 control
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        7 May 18 11:07 primary-backup -> ../dm-5
brw-rw----  1 root disk 252,   2 May 18 11:31 primary-data
brw-rw----  1 root disk 252,   1 May 18 11:31 primary-data-real
brw-rw----  1 root disk 252,   4 May 18 11:31 primary-snap
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        7 May 18 11:07 primary-snap-cow -> ../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        7 May 18 11:07 primary-system -> ../dm-0
```

At this point, if I run `mount -a`, I can now view the partition at my mount point of /mnt/data. However, this does not survive a reboot.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for getting the missing devices to show up in /dev/mapper consistently?

Comment: Perhaps you included the wrong line from fstab. You said `/dev/mapper/primary-backup` is referenced in fstab but isn't showing up in `/dev/mapper`. However, when you run `ls -al /dev/mapper` there is a line that reads `lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 May 18 11:07 primary-backup -> ../dm-5`, so `/dev/mapper/primary-backup` *is* in `/dev/mapper`. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry. I've added the correct line from fstab.